# Python program to remove invalid parentheses

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, balanced-delimiters

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-invalid-parentheses/) -

> *Remove the minimum number of invalid parentheses in order to make the
>   input string valid. Return all possible results.*
>
> ***Note -***
>
> *The input string may contain letters other than the parentheses `(`
>   and `)`.*

Here is my solution to this challenge -

> ```
> def remove_invalid_parentheses(s):
>
>     removed = 0
>     results = {s}
>     count = {"(": 0, ")": 0}
>     for i, c in enumerate(s):
>         if c == ")" and count["("] == count[")"]:
>             new_results = set()
>             while results:
>                 result = results.pop()
>                 for j in range(i - removed + 1):
>                     if result[j] == ")":
>                         new_results.add(result[:j] + result[j + 1:])
>             results = new_results
>             removed += 1
>         else:
>             if c in count:
>                 count[c] += 1
>     count = {"(": 0, ")": 0}
>     i = len(s)
>     ll = len(s) - removed
>     for ii in range(ll - 1, -1, -1):
>         i-=1
>         c = s[i]
>         if c == "(" and count["("] == count[")"]:
>             new_results = set()
>             while results:
>                 result = results.pop()
>                 for j in range(ii, ll):
>                     if result[j] == "(":
>                         new_results.add(result[:j] + result[j + 1:])
>             results = new_results
>             ll -= 1
>         else:
>             if c in count:
>                 count[c] += 1
>     return list(results)
> ```

Explanation -

- Scan from left to right, make sure `count["("] >= count[")"]`.
- Then scan from right to left, make sure `count["("] <= count[")"]`.

Here are some inputs/outputs -

> ```
> print(remove_invalid_parentheses("()())()"))
> >>> ["()()()", "(())()"]
>
> print(remove_invalid_parentheses("(a)())()"))
> >>> ["(a)()()", "(a())()"]
>
> print(remove_invalid_parentheses(")("))
> >>> [""]
> ```

Here are the times taken for each output -

```
%timeit remove_invalid_parentheses("()())()")
6.54 µs ± 176 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit remove_invalid_parentheses("(a)())()")
8.43 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit remove_invalid_parentheses(")(")
3.69 µs ± 67.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test, consistent behavior & data structure**

Trying to add tests for the code based on the example of input/output provided led to the following result: the behavior is not consistent : in particular the order of the elements in the returned list is not always the same.

The root cause for this is that we are using sets in the logic only to convert to list at the end.

A solution would be to return `sorted(results)` at the end. An alternative would be to just return a set instead of trying to convert to list.

Then, we get the following automated tests:

```
print(remove_invalid_parentheses("()())()") == {"(())()", "()()()"})
print(remove_invalid_parentheses("(a)())()") == {"(a())()", "(a)()()"})
print(remove_invalid_parentheses(")(") == {""})
```

It would make sense to try to rewrite it as unit-tests using a proper unit-test framework but I will stop here as this is enough for me to keep working.

**More explicit loop**

I tend to find loops based on `for ii in range(ll - 1, -1, -1)` very error-prone/hard to understand because of the number of tweaks on both sides of the range. I'd suggest a much more explicit alternative: `for ii in reversed(range(ll)):`.

**Similar indices**

As `ii` will go over `]ll, 0]` which is `]len(s) - removed, 0]`, i will go over `]len(s), removed]`.

The difference between the indices is always `removed`, we have `ii + removed == i`: we can get rid of the `i` variable. We can take this chance to rename `ii` into `i`.

At this stage, we have:

```
def remove_invalid_parentheses(s):
    removed = 0
    results = {s}
    count = {"(": 0, ")": 0}
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c == ")" and count["("] == count[")"]:
            new_results = set()
            while results:
                result = results.pop()
                for j in range(i - removed + 1):
                    if result[j] == ")":
                        new_results.add(result[:j] + result[j + 1:])
            results = new_results
            removed += 1
        elif c in count:
                count[c] += 1
    count = {"(": 0, ")": 0}
    ll = len(s) - removed
    for i in reversed(range(ll)):
        c = s[i + removed]
        if c == "(" and count["("] == count[")"]:
            new_results = set()
            while results:
                result = results.pop()
                for j in range(i, ll):
                    if result[j] == "(":
                        new_results.add(result[:j] + result[j + 1:])
            results = new_results
            ll -= 1
        elif c in count:
                count[c] += 1
    return results


print(remove_invalid_parentheses("()())()") == {"(())()", "()()()"})
print(remove_invalid_parentheses("()())))()") == {"(())()", "()()()"})
print(remove_invalid_parentheses("(a)())()") == {"(a())()", "(a)()()"})
print(remove_invalid_parentheses(")(") == {""})
```

(I took this chance to add a new test case)

**More explicit loop again**

We want to iterate in reversed order over the beginning of the `s` string. Here again, we can try to make things more explicit and remove some computation as we go:

```
    for i, c in enumerate(reversed(s[removed:])):
        if c == "(" and count["("] == count[")"]:
            new_results = set()
            while results:
                result = results.pop()
                for j in range(len(s) - i - removed - 1, ll):
                    if result[j] == "(":
                        new_results.add(result[:j] + result[j + 1:])
            results = new_results
            ll -= 1
        elif c in count:
                count[c] += 1
```

In order to test this more throughly, I took this chance to add the following test case:

```
print(remove_invalid_parentheses("((((((((()(") == {"()"})
```

**More beautiful loops**

Instead of using a combination of `while` and `pop` to iterate over the elements of a set, you can just use `for`:

```
        for result in results:
```

*Work in progress: I have to go. I may continue in the future.*